# Jquery fade in an image on website load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadein

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JQuery Page Loading Effect</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            div.hidden { display: none }
        </style>
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('div').fadeOut(1);
            $('div').removeClass('hidden');
            $('div').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    </script>
    <body>
        <div class="hidden">
            <p>This is some text.</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I took this code from a mate, as I'm not really experienced with JQuery, so this doesn't make sense to me. I was just wondering how I could improve this code so that the text eases in during the load of the web page. Thanks in advance!

Comment: why are you fadingOut at first. That is not required at all since that div element was already hidden.

Comment: CSS should be in a `<style>` tag.

Comment: When you remove class hidden the text will appear no need to fadeIn()

Answer (score 1):

The fadeOut is not Necessary. 
And actually you do not need to remove the class *hidden*
Calling *fadeIn* will display the text

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

You use *fadeIn* to display the text with a little transition. If you don´t need it, just removing the class *hidden* will work too